# I need to show profile image in round shape

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_group_profile_image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_group_profile_image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/save"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

binding.appbar.groupImage.apply {
                    shapeAppearanceModel = shapeAppearanceModel
                        .toBuilder()
                        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 8f)
                        .build()
                    load(path)
                }
```

**this is my xml and kotlin code for round image, **

this is my output what I'm getting [image]

I need to show like this [image]

help me to solve this problem.

Comment: use this dependency https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this style in the **style.xml** file:

```
<style name="circleImageView" parent="">
  <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
  <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library which is quite easy to use and provide you profile picture in round shape.

The initial step is to add gradel dependencies to your android project.

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
```

After this, use the given below snippet inside your layout file or where you want to use a round profile picture.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/profile_image"
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

For more info, you can check the GitHub [link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)